# Crear una tabla nueva si la fecha no es igual

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, codeigniter

Estoy recorriendo un foreach y los datos los cargo en una tabla, pero deseo cargar los datos en diferentes vistas de tabla dependiendo de la `fecha` ejemplo si la variable `fecha='11-11-2017'` hay 3 campos que cargue esos datos ahi y si la fecha es diferente que siga cargando pero en otra tabla.

```
<table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Orden</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php if ($seguimientos): ?>
    <?php foreach ($seguimientos as $seguimiento): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $seguimiento-> fecha; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $seguimiento-> NroSolicitud; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $seguimiento-> maquina; ?>
        </td>


    </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</table>
```

Algo asi, adjunto una foto[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme explicado bien. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear un array asociativo usando las fechas como llaves.  Algo asi:

```
<?php if ($seguimientos): ?>
<?php $fechas = array();
      foreach ($seguimientos as $seguimiento) {
         $fechas[$seguimiento-> fecha][] = $seguimiento;

      }
?>
<?php foreach ($fechas as $fecha): ?>
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Fecha</th>
        <th>Orden</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
<?php   foreach ($fecha as $seguimiento): ?>
<tr>
    <td>
        <?php echo $seguimiento-> fecha; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $seguimiento-> NroSolicitud; ?>
    </td>
    <td>
        <?php echo $seguimiento-> maquina; ?>
    </td>
</tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Funciono muy bien gracias!